# I'm unable to debug what is the problem in linking the directory path on git bash command line

Tags: r, command-line, directory

I am trying to enter the RStudio's path as can be seen in the screenshot but it gives me error "No such file or directory".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are spaces in your path and you tried to replace them with underscores, that's why it doesn't find the file.

If you want to use spaces in the path, put the path in quotes:

```
cd "~/Desktop/trying by this route"
```

Note that `~` (tilde) doesn't expand to your home directory in quotes.

Another solution is to escape spaces:

```
cd ~/Desktop/trying\ by\ this\ route
```

Comment: Yes.That worked although I've had to enter the whole path now though,not just append the remaining of the location. I.e I,ve had to enter whole of "/c/Users/HP/Desktop/trying by this route/". Even after the command line being present in the HP folder already.

Comment: Yes, I've updated the answer, `~` doesn't expand to the home directory in quotes. So another solution is to escape spaces.